# What can we put as parameter of okhttp3 MediaType.parse method for an audio file?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, media-type

I found that for uploading images using Android with a RequestBody, we can use MediaType.parse("image/jpeg").

However, what would be the parameter for an audio file ?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can get mime type of any file using this method:

```
public static String getMimeType(String url) {
     String type = null;
     String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
     if (extension != null) {
        type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
     }
     return type;
}
```

To get mime, call `String mime = getMimeType(file.getAbsolutePath());`

You can find list of all mimes [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.okhttp/okhttp/20120626/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java#MimeUtils). And thus, mime for audio will be `audio/mpeg`. But I will still recommend using `getMimeTypeFromExtension` than hardcoding the value.

Comment: why does `MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url)` return nothing?